# How to disable an action in devise, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails and Devise. There is an `Admin` model created by devise. 
How can i disable creating admins? (how to disable `create` and `new` actions is devise controller)

My Rails version is 6.0.1

Comment: What about Registerable module? https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Registerable . Without it you can't create new users (Admins in your case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `skip:` option with [`devise_for`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_for-instance_method) to skip the generation of routes for any of the Devise controllers:

```
devise_for :admins, skip: :registrations
```

If you still want to let the admins update and destroy their accounts you need to manually re-add those routes:

```
devise_for :admins, skip: :registrations
devise_scope :admin do
  resource :admin_registration, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy],
                                path: 'admins',
                                controller: 'devise/registrations'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling `new` and `create` means disabling `Sign up` and that is provided by Devise's `registerable` module. In `admin` model, remove `:registerable` from the following list

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, ...
```

It will disable the `registration` functionality provided by devise.